# Is it possible to boot Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi and PC on same pendrive?

Tags: raspberry-pi, x86-64, boot

I have a Raspberry Pi 400 booting Ubuntu from a USB/SSD.

I was wondering if there is a way to boot from same pendrive but on a PC, of course with a corresponding Ubuntu for x86-64 installed on a different partition on that SSD.

With a third partition for data, it would be the best of both worlds, using the Pi for easy portability and a PC when requiring more "power"

Anyone has experimented with such thing?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.  Could be on-topic on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/.  Or if there's a stack site for RPi.

Answer (score 1):

Check out BerryBoot, that might help with that.

If that doesn't work, see answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38888.

> No. You could (I believe this is what something like berryboot probably does; I haven't used it) load a minimal root fs, possibly from an initramfs, present the user with options, and then switch the root filesystem (which is what initramfs kernels always do), but obviously there is a bit of work involved.
> Alternately, you could write your own bootloader code, but this is even more work, and may require some proprietary knowledge (I'm not sure).

Also see https://superuser.com/a/1520139/1167517, which details how to boot from selected partition on a **Raspberry PI 3**.

Obvious disclaimer: **Playing with boot files is highly dangerous and can cause a non bootable drive. Make sure to backup files from SD card before doing this.**